# forward all traffic from a virtual IP to a vm inside lan

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, linux-networking, nat

I'm trying to set up a specific NAT but i'm a bit stuck here.

My setup is as follow :

- 3 dedicated with one nic each, which run a few VM, interconnected with tinc in the subnet 10.100.0.0/16
- 1 VPS with 2 nics, 1 nic with one public IP and the second one with a lot of public IP (25 at least), this VPS is also connected with dedicateds via Tinc in the same subnet 10.100.0.0/16

VM are perfectly able to reach dedicated servers and the vps, and it's the same for the dedicated and vps toward the VM.

Dedicated 1 : 10.100.0.10
Dedicated 1 : 10.100.0.20
Dedicated 1 : 10.100.0.30
VM 1 : 10.100.2.3
VM 2 : 10.100.2.4
VM 3 : 10.100.2.5
VPS : 10.100.0.101

All the VMs use the VPS IP as gateway, it looks like this :

```
root@test-ubuntu:~# ip a l dev ens3
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:c1:fa:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.100.2.3/16 brd 10.100.255.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fec1:faf5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@test-ubuntu:~# ip r s dev ens3
default via 10.100.0.101 
10.100.0.0/16  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.100.2.3 
169.254.169.254 via 10.100.2.1
```

Issue is that I want to use all the Public Ip I have on this VPS to access the VM directly. I know I have to do some nat but after a few hours testing differents approch and reading documentation I admit that I completely stuck.

```
root@network1:~# ip a l dev ens3
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:86:e6:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 145.YYY.XXX.60/32 brd 145.YYY.XXX.60 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@network1:~# ip a l dev ens6
3: ens6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:78:93:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 147.AAA.BBB.97/27 brd 147.AAA.BBB.127 scope global ens6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 147.AAA.BBB.98/27 brd 147.AAA.BBB.127 scope global secondary ens6:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 147.AAA.BBB.99/27 brd 147.AAA.BBB.127 scope global secondary ens6:2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
                           [....]
    inet 147.AAA.BBB.124/27 brd 147.AAA.BBB.127 scope global secondary ens6:27
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 147.AAA.BBB.125/27 brd 147.AAA.BBB.127 scope global secondary ens6:28
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

For now, my rules are empty (i only show the nat table but it's the same for the general table) :

```
root@haproxy-1:~# iptables -t nat -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 96 packets, 3096 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 96 packets, 3096 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

As my goal is to redirect all the trafic that come to one IP (let's say 147.AAA.BBB.98) to the VM which has the IP 10.100.2.3 I came up with this :

External to VM :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 147.AAA.BBB.98 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.100.2.3
```

Vm to External :

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.100.2.3 -j SNAT --to-source 147.AAA.BBB.98
```

Ipforward is of course enable on the VPS

But it doesn't work :/

if I make some Tcpdump on the VPS I see the packet coming from outside but nothing goes to the VM. If I try to ping the outside from the VM, I see the packet coming inside the VPS, packet are sent but nothing is received.

However, if I do it with the main IP of the VPS (the one on ens3) everything work as expected

I'm wondering if it couldn't be the fact that the tinc VPN is running on the interface ens3 and so the packet should be forwarded from one interface to another

Do you have any idea what I could do to fix this ?

Edit : IP on the second interface are not on the same subnet than IP on the main Interface, so I had to use another route table, here are what my route looks like :

```
root@haproxy-1:~# ip r s
default via 145.XXX.YYY.1 dev ens3 
10.100.0.0/16 dev prov  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.100.0.101 
145.XXX.YYY.1 dev ens3  scope link 
147.AAA.BBB.96/27 dev ens6  proto kernel  scope link  src 147.AAA.BBB.97 

root@haproxy-1:~# ip r s table 101
default via 147.AAA.BBB.126 dev ens6
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have setup the gateway for the rest public IP attached to the second interface? Are you able to connect to your VPS using one of them?

Comment: Yes, I'm perfectly able to connect to the VPS using IP on the second interfaces. I'll edit to show route in my first post.

Comment: Did you have enabled IP forward on the VPS?

Comment: Indeed, ip forward is enabled, my mistake, I forgot to add it in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself because I found a solution (not sure it will be the best one thought).

As both interfaces use different GW I did use routing table to get both working, no issue with these.

Rules were set properly :

```
root@haproxy-1:~# ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local 
32765:  from 147.AAA.BBB.96/27 lookup 101 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

But What I didn't know was the fact that I also need a rule to tell that trafic that come from the 10.100.0.0/16 need to use the table 101

So I did add this rule :

```
ip rule add from 10.100.2.0/16 lookup 101
```

My table looks now to this :

```
root@haproxy-1:~# ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local 
32764:  from 10.100.2.0/16 lookup 101 
32765:  from 147.AAA.BBB.96/27 lookup 101 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

And the traffic is perfectly routed to the VM and from the VM to the outside.
If I do a nmap on the IP forwarded to the VM (147.AAA.BBB.98) I only see the open port of the VM and not one of the VPS.

Note that I did use this explanation to solve my issue :
http://www.rjsystems.nl/en/2100-adv-routing.php

Anyway it's now works as I want